# Is it possible to redirect queries to another server?

Tags: sql-server, network, proxy

I want to set up a server that redirects queries. It would receive incoming SQL Server traffic, redirect to the actual SQL Server, and return results back to the client.

Is this possible? What are my options?

Comment: Interesting! I would love to know why!

Comment: Is this a database or a network question? I.e would a port forward meet your needs?

Comment: ...or, I don’t know, DNS? What is the actual problem you’re trying to solve? Are you just trying to avoid correcting an obsolete connection string?

Comment: I'm hoping to [use NitroAccelerator on the proxy server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203790/can-i-use-tds-compression-with-azure-sql-db-or-managed-instances) to compress network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

First Things that come to my mind:

1 Linked Servers
You can use a linked Server and forward all requests to it, but then the calling Code or Programm must use prepared procedures or views that use the linked Server.

2 SQL alias, but I guess this is not what you are looking for.

But I wonder why would you do that? I can't See advantages.

Think about license Costs. They may double if you Do this kind of scenario in a production Environment.

Monitoring and tracing : administrative effort increases and again Costs.

And Security. It's Trick to configure linked Server connection to reuse the calling Logins to make sure you dont Open All Gates to anyone who can access the "Proxy".

Comment: Plus, Microsoft has introduced a security loophole in powershell that allows any SA user to decrypt the SQL Logins!!

Answer (score 0):

You say in your comments

> I'm hoping to [use NitroAccelerator on the proxy server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203790/can-i-use-tds-compression-with-azure-sql-db-or-managed-instances) to compress network traffic. – Steven Hibble Apr 16 '18 at 21:46

The link goes to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203790/can-i-use-tds-compression-with-azure-sql-db-or-managed-instances

The link is currently dead, but googling finds this

> Accelerate and secure end-to-end SQL Server network traffic with easy to deploy endpoint-based software that requires no configuration or downtime. [Source](https://nitrosphere.com/nitroaccelerator/)

I would seem that your desire is to get quicker access to the "actual SQL Server" by setting up NitroAccelerator on one (1) server.  It would seem like the better solution is to just install your NitroAccelerator solution on all the "actual SQL Server"

Adding another layer going through one server to another is only going to add complexity and slowness.